# Resume the progress view progress from certain point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I have a custom circular progress bar in `UITableViewCell`.

```
[progressView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
[progressView setProgress: 1.0 animated: YES];
```

To stop the progress at certain point I am using below code:

```
[progressView setProgress: 0.5 animated: YES];
```

Now I want to resume the progress from 0.5 to 1.0. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which library is use for above

Comment: M13ProgressView, M13ProgressViewPie: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite

Comment: @sadikhasan could you please accept an answer, or tell us if you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

Based on `M13ProgressViewBar.m:216` ([link](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite/blob/master/Classes/ProgressViews/M13ProgressViewBar.m#L216)) you should be able to do that just by calling

```
[progressView setProgress:1.0 animated:YES];
```

again, as it should be resuming progress from the current state (0.5 in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna implement the `prepareforreuse` method in your custom `UITableViewcell` implementation, which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

save your progress while this cell got resused, then when that particular cell reappears in the table resume your animation in progress.

Comment: was is helpful, or need more clue ? @sadik hasan